# Частые запросы SQL

Tags: sqlite3

Давно мучает вопрос: каким образом устроен функционал чатов, а именно частые запросы в БД.
Очень интересно как реализованы они, например виджеты онлайн консультанта на сайтах. Давненько делал чат на php/mysql в итоге хостинг закрыл соединение, потому что в чате было 5 человек и с каждого отправлялся запрос каждую секунду - это конечно идиотизм, но это был мой первый опыт.

Сейчас возникла идея похожая, но я так и не могу понять как лучше или как надёжнее всё реализовать. Посоветуйте куда идти (двигаться в смысле).

Возможно сделать с помощью SQLite3? Ведь это всего лишь файл, а не сервер уже. Возможно я не прав.

Comment: Сейчас браузеры поддерживают много новых технологий, например WebSocket, который позволяет постоянно поддерживать соединение с сервером, а не запрашивать раз в секунду. А сервер сам шлет данные, как только они появляются. Их даже в БД писать не обязатльно, получил от одного клиента и сразу остальным разослал

Comment: Спасибо уважаемый Mike сейчас буду изучать, один раз слышал, но теперь детально всё посмотрю, спасибо большое.

Comment: @Mike а раньше можно можно было просто лонг полинг использовать для http запросов.

Comment: Вот на аглицком, но с картинками http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброго времени суток! В свое время во время рабочего процесса удосужилось тестировать websocket для банковского клиента, один из бизнес процессов был как раз таки был именно чат. Я врятле вам смогу помочь в техническом плане реализации вашей проблемы, но уверен что погуглив webSocket для вашего яп вы найдете нужные ответы.

Comment: Всем спасибо, думаю я справлюсь)